# How can I make an image fade into color upon hover?

Tags: html, css

I'm *very* new to web dev right now, and I'm currently trying to make an image fade into color upon hovering over it. This is what I've got right now:

```
    html:
         <body>
                <img src=imgmonochrome.jpg id=img1>
            </body>


    css:
        #img1 {
            position: top right;
            height:49%;
            width:49%;
            transition: content 0.5s ease;
        }
        #img1:hover {
            transition: content 0.5s;
            content: url('imgcolor.jpg');
        }
```

The image will switch, but will not fade in.

I've looked all over for answers on this, but I can't find any that use just HTML and CSS (cause I'm illiterate in javascript/jQuery ((but going to learn very soon for this very reason)))

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES**, this is possible... But not in the traditional sense.

In order to accomplish this, you'll need to forgo `<img />`, and instead make use of two images presented with **[`content: url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)** in **[`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)** and **[`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)** pseudo-classes. Set the `:before` to be your starting image, and `:after` to be your target image. Then set the **[`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)** of `:after` to `0` by default, and set the two pseudo-elements to sit on top of one another. Finally, set a `:hover` rule for both `:before` and `:after` which toggles their `opacity`, and use **[`transition: opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)** to control the fade.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.image:before {
  content: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/00FFFF");
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.image:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  content: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FFFF/FF0000");
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.image:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: Good answer, but I'm running into another issue; the image is now taking up the entire page when hovered over, and when not is cut off by a quarter. I have a grid thing going on, where there are 4 images in quadrants. Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Comment: I couldn't say for sure without seeing the problem, but there's no reason that the image should take up the entire page. Maybe try setting a `width` or `height` constraint manually. You can use `width: calc(25%)` or similar if need be. The 'being cut-off' issue sounds like a call for `z-index`. And don't forget, you can always add the two `position: absolute` images inside a `position: relative` container! That will keep them on top of each other, whilst also maintaining flow :)

Comment: I'm not too sure what stackoverflow's policy on outside links are but oh well. Here's a screenshot of both my code and the problem I am having:
- https://gyazo.com/f8180e185bfb675f19e2fbb90f3d994c
- https://gyazo.com/07f9ebe083b0db13abaf6052223d9bb3
- https://gyazo.com/8f436d81f99a224125474a841c2d2016 - I am doing a project where I have to make an informational website on four U.S. presidents, and I'm trying to design that as the home page as context. Also, the colored image is appearing on the bottom upon hover, which is why you can't see it in the gif.

Answer (score 0):

Remove content from the transition and use img tag to set image

```
<img src="imgmonochrome.jpg" id="img1">

        #img1 {
            position: top right;
            height:49%;
            width:49%;
            transition: 0.5s ease;
        }
        #img1:hover {
            opacity: 0.3;
            background: url(imgcolor.jpg);
        }
```

Alternatively,

```
<img src="imgcolor.jpg" id="img1">
#img1 {
   filter: gray;
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
   -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
#img1:hover {
   filter: none;
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```